# anchor tag is insert multiple times

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

The anchor tag I have specified in my code is inserted into multiple places when viewed in the browser.

What causes this problem? And what can I do to solve this?

```
                 <a  href="{{ route('candidate.company.view', $company->id) }}" class="block no-overflow">
                    <div class="row space-inside-sides-sm">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-light shadow-accent space-inside-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $company->logo) }}" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <p class="vacancy-title">{{ $company->title }}</p>
                                    <span>Amsterdam, NL</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        Followers: {{ $company->followers->count() }}
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

[image]

Comment: show your full code here

Comment: Yeah I think it will better if you show your full code here

Comment: The full code is not relevant here. If I place this code on it's on, in an empty page, the problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the nested anchor tag. Nested anchor tags are not allowed. Because of the nested anchor tag, the first anchor tag is closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check you code for some JS/JQuery may clone this code also try anchor without `class="block no-overflow"`

Comment: an anchor tag is by default an inline element. These classes 'block' and 'no-overflow' are making sure that the anchor tag is taking up the space of its children.